# Error: "Specified SQL Server not found" when connecting SQL Server to R Markdown

Tags: r, sql-server, r-markdown, odbc, dbi

I'm getting this error when trying to connect my SQL Server to R Markdown

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1138: 01S00
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Specified SQL server not found. 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
```

This is my connection code

```
{r Connection to SQL Database,echo=T, warning=F, message=F, eval=T}
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "MY-PC/SQLEXPRESS",
                      Database = "Cyclistic",
                      Port = 8524)
```

I have no experience in these types of things, I only want to show my SQL queries in the markdown.

If there's some other way that I could do this please tell me, or if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: If you are defining the Instance name (`SQLEXPRESS` in this case) you normally wouldn't provide the port. SQL Express, normally, uses a dynamic port as well, so the next time the service starts, it could easily be different.

Comment: @ThomA what If I changed the port using SQL Server Client Network, would that change anything? I think it's something with my SQL Server setup and not the R markdown, but like I said I'm not really familiar with these things.

Comment: There isn't going to be a host name `MY-PC/SQLEXPRESS` resolvable in DNS. Instance names are typically separated from host names using the backslash character (\\) instead of the slash (/), what happens if you use `Server = "MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS"` or `Server = "MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it was "MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS" originally but I had to change it because the backslash is not excepted in R, so I thought a normal slash would work.

Comment: *"backslash not accepted in R"* ... did you try `"MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"`?